# Blogger wont save template with this javascript in it

Tags: javascript, blogger

The template wont save when I have this piece of javascript in it:

```
    var minutes = secs / 60;
    var seconds = secs % 60;

     if ( seconds<10 ) {
            var extrazero = &quot;:0&quot;
    }
    else {
             extrazero = &quot;:&quot;
    }
```

I have narrowed it down to the < symbol in the condition. If I change that to an = sign it saves but if I have the < symbol there it has an error saying the following:

Error parsing XML, line 2741, column 16: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

EDIT: I found someone saying that putting  cdata tags around the javascript worked for them. it does save but doesnt work.

```
    //<![CDATA[   javascript here   //]]>
```

Comment: did you try `&lt;`? It's weird, but you are using `&quot;`... (though I think `CDATA` should have the same effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply Parse your Javascript code Here http://www.blogcrowds.com/resources/parse_html.php then paste in Blogger :)